# read email Using Pop3 client on asp.net web page

Tags: c#, email, pop3

I want to read Emails through pop3.
On my asp.net web page how to do let me know,

which control should I use for showing email?

Answer (score 11):

Here are a couple of libraries allowing you to retrieve messages from a POP3 server:

- [C#Mail](http://csharpmail.codeplex.com/)
- [OpenPop](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpop/)
- [Pop3.Net](http://weblogs.shockbyte.com.ar/rodolfof/archive/2008/07/07/pop3.net-library.aspx)
- [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/despop3client.aspx)

Comment: @ Darin Dimitrov ,Can you give me please specific code or url ? 
I need like as www.pageflakes.com (email widget)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim pop3Client As Pop3Client
Dim i As Integer =1
pop3Client = New Pop3Client
pop3Client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, True)
pop3Client.Authenticate("myname@gmail.com", "mypassword")
Dim inbox_count As Integer = pop3Client.GetMessageCount
Do While (inbox_count >= i)
Dim message As Message = pop3Client.GetMessage(i)
Dim messagePart As MessagePart = message.MessagePart.MessageParts(0)
messagePart.BodyEncoding.GetString(messagePart.Body)'give you message body
message.Headers.From.Address'give you from address
message.Headers.DateSent'date of mail send
message.Headers.Subject'subject of the mail
i= i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: For this answer to be useful, you'd have to be telling people where "Pop3Client" comes from, since it's not a standard ASP.NET class.